# Connecting an Android ListView onClick to another Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, mp3, android-sdcard, onitemclick

I am making a MP3 player Android App. I want to start another activity from a ListView click that opens up the artist directory to show the songs from that one artist. I based my code off of the [Android tutorial][1].

This below is in my onCreate in ArtistList.java

```
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SongList.class);

            String artistSongPath = artistsList.get(position).get("artistPath");//gets artist SDcard path

            System.out.println("artistSongPath = " + artistSongPath); //prints out correct path

            intent.putExtra("A_S_PATH", artistSongPath); //puts the artistSongPath static A_S_Path

            startActivity(intent); //start the intent
        }
    });
```

At the top of my ArtistList.java I have

```
    public final static String A_S_PATH = "wecode.mp3playerapp.MESSAGE";
```

And in my SongList.java

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.song_list);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String path = intent.getStringExtra(ArtistList.A_S_PATH) + "/";
    System.out.println(path);
    try {
        File fp = new File(path);
        findArtistSongs(fp);
    }catch(NullPointerException npe){
        System.out.println("Could not find path.");
    }

}
```

A_S_Path is null and I am not getting into my catch. Please help! This is my first app!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.song_list);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String path = intent.getStringExtra("A_S_PATH") + "/"; //here is the line that I changed
    System.out.println(path);
    try {
        File fp = new File(path);
        findArtistSongs(fp);
    }catch(NullPointerException npe){
        System.out.println("Could not find path.");
    }
```

Comment: glad it helps , be carefull to those tags , they have to be exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

In your ArtistList.java you have:

```
intent.putExtra("A_S_PATH", artistSongPath);
```

But in SongList.java, you have:

```
String path = intent.getStringExtra(ArtistList.A_S_PATH) + "/";
```

Have you noticed the **"A_S_PATH"** is different from **ArtistList.A_S_PATH** you have defined?